# problem mounting second harddrive with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I just installed ubuntu and im completly new with ubuntu.

I am trying to get my second harddrive to work but it won't.
I've used some guides like [this](http://sourcedigit.com/8194-customize-ubuntu-14-04-mount-hard-disk-partitionsdrives-automatically-system-startup)
But still no success.

The problem is that it doesn't see my `ntfs` as a valid one.
I don't really understand what this means. this is the message the terminal gives me when trying to mount the hard drive:

```
robert@Robert-Linux:~$ sudo mount -a 

NTFS signature is missing.  
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument   
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.  
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?  
robert@Robert-Linux:~$
```

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Greetings Robert

EDIT

/etc/fstab file content:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d91f5c8b-30d0-4bc7-85cb-e3b26d2e9c1d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=81cc1c05-8435-4d18-8af5-049d092294cb none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0

/dev/sdb1 /media/disk2   ntfs   defaults        0    0
```

Comment: Robert, the article you linked to says to change the text file at /etc/fstab.  Did you do that?  If so, would you please post the contents of that file so we can help

Comment: yes i did change that here is what is in the /etc/fstab file: **/dev/sdb1 /media/disk2  ntfs  defaults   0  0** For the full content of the file i edited the main question

Comment: Signature missing is typically that is it not formatted even though partition table says it is NTFS. All NTFS partitions have to have a NTFS boot signature with start & size of NTFS partition. IF you resized it you need to run chkdsk. Or if you installed grub to sdb1's PBR partition boot sector then you need further repairs.

Comment: ... then that partition isn't formatted as ntfs.